# How I can parse an encrypted paragraph using Frequency analysis?

Tags: c#, c++, security, encryption, frequency-analysis

Currently working in a college project where i have to create a program that is able to decrypt basics encryption with frequency analysis automatically without any user feedback. The program is going to read the encryption without spaces like:

> GFSWMYOGLGDVSMFSFNKYHOSUESLLMRSPCWSBFGWPOLDMFRQMRSPLOGCPFUMUPCCSKSFOHDMPFOSXOGCOISLMESDMFRQMRSDGFRSFGQRIOGCPDDGFSLISSOGKLGMFUOISFWSNGQFOOISGNNQKKSFNSLGCSMNIDSOOSKWSNMDDOISEGLOCKSJQSFODYGNNQKKPFRDSOOSKOISCPKLOOISFSXOEGLOGNNQKKPFRDSOOSKOISLSNGFUOISCGDDGWPFREGLOGNNQKKPFRDSOOSKOISOIPKUMFULGGFQFOPDWSMNNGQFOCGKMDDOISUPCCSKSFODSOOSKLPFOISHDMPFOSXOLMEHDSOISFWSDGGBMOOISNPHISKOSXOWSWMFOOGLGDVSMFUWSMDLGNDMLLPCYPOLLYEAGDLWSCPFUOISEGLOGNNQKKPFRLYEAGDMFUNIMFRSPOOGOISCGKEGCOISCPKLODSOOSKGCOISHDMPFOSXOLMEHDSOISFSXOEGLONGEEGFLYEAGDPLNIMFRSUOGOISCGKEGCOISLSNGFUDSOOSKMFUOISCGDDGWPFREGLONGEEGFLYEAGDPLNIMFRSUOGOISCGKEGCOISOIPKUDSOOSKMFULGGFQFOPDWSMNNGQFOCGKMDDLYEAGDLGCOISNKYHOGRKMEWSWMFOOGLGDVS

Don't need any coding help but looking for an idea on how to parse this.

I already have an English dictionary with 120k words, the first 15k words are the most used in English. I am currently trying to solve this by using N-grams and substitution of most commons letters used / words used. 
Appreciate any idea / better way to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: Will [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) help?

Comment: This way i need to use the user feedback's..

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of times each letter appears and compare it to usage tables in english. It should be simple to identify e's for instance. The less frequently used letters will be harder to identify, but if you already have some information that is reliable from the easier letters, you could try different possibilities and then compare the words it makes with your dictonary.

Comment: i did a code where i can sent to dictionary "-a--aa" and i get back a list of words that have the letter A in those positions. For me the challenging part is parsing the encryption when is all together.... this is not hard by looking at it.  but coding it have been a pain for me. also the frequency tables are not 100% accurate on most cases.

Answer (score 0):

When I've done these kind of things I've created an array of English letter frequencies to compare against, and another array containing the letter frequencies of the ciphertext. Simply doing correlation calculations between the two arrays should give you the correct answer automatically (i.e. minimize the sum of the square difference for a given offset of the cipher frequency array).